# Perform action after load event has completed

Tags: jquery, load

I have some jQuery to make a div 'flash', but I want it to only happen after the page has loaded into the div, rather than instantly.

```
$('#div').load("page.php");
$('#div').fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the callback parameter of `load()` to provide a function which will be executed after the AJAX request completes. Try this:

```
$('#div').load("page.php", function() {
  $(this).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
});
```

You should note though that you can achieve the blinking effect with CSS alone. This will make the JS more succinct, and also perform better:

```js
// place this within the callback function
$('#div').addClass('blink_me');
```

```css
.blink_me { animation: blinker .5s linear 3; }
@keyframes blinker { 50% { opacity: 0; } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
  <span>Some content added by load()</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`load()` does have a callback and you should use that. It gets executed only after the `load()` is done. Perfect for what you are looking for:

```
$('#div').load("page.php", function() {
  $(this).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
});
```